# Calculate rotation respective of mp3 length

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation, audio

Im trying to create a set of turntables, I have successfully loaded an mp3 and can play it, Now in my turntable movieclip I have another movieclip for the arm which I can alter the rotation of easily.

what im struggling with is tying the mp3 to the rotation. Im wanting the arm to slowly rotate as the mp3 plays. The arm needs to start at -4 and end at +14 (rotation) when the sound starts and finishes.

now iv tried to calculate the length of the mp3 with the following code

```
mp3Length = (_mp3.bytesTotal/(_mp3.bytesLoaded/_mp3.length))/1000;
```

so i load a song and trace the value of mp3Length and the traced value is 352.8620408163265

but when i look at the same song in itunes the length is 5:53.

So im guessing something is wrong with the way i'm calculating the length.

I am then trying to rotate the arm with the following code . . .

```
leftDeck.arm.rotation = 18 / mp3Length;
```

that is 18 the difference between -4 and +14 but this is rotating the arm way to quickly.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction to working this out?

Many Thanks

UPDATE-----

ok iv found this code which correctly identifies the length of the mp3

```
var Milliseconds:Number = (_mp3.bytesTotal / (_mp3.bytesLoaded / _mp3.length));

var Minutes:uint = Math.floor(Milliseconds/60000);
var Seconds:uint = (Milliseconds%60000);
var SecondsTens:uint = Math.floor(Seconds/10000);

Seconds = Math.ceil(Seconds%10000)
Seconds /= 1000;

trace(Minutes + ":" + SecondsTens + "" + Seconds);
```

but im still struggling to tie the rotation to the length.

Comment: Is your question really "how do I determine the (time) length of an MP3 file?".

Comment: if your mp3 has variable bitrate VBR, this calculation wont work

Comment: @OliCharlesworth no i have successfully calculated the length. my question is how do i make the arm rotate from -4 to +14 in the time it takes the loaded mp3 to play

M4tchB0X3r could you explain a bit more. if i type _mp3. there is no codehint for a variable bitrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need to know the bitrate to calculate the length of the MP3 since the Sound class has a `length` property that reports the length in milliseconds.

The `SoundChannel` class has a `position` property which reports the current position of the sound being played in milliseconds.

This means that you can calculate the percentage of rotation based on `[soundChannel].position / [sound].length` and apply that to the rotation:

```
leftDeck.arm.rotation = 18 * (_mp3Channel.position / _mp3.length) - 4;
```

The reason you subtract 4 is because your range is -4 to 14.

Comment: You my good sir are a legend! had to tweak the last number as i got the rotation wrong but this works! thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you! Good luck with the rest of the project.